# ros2 humble integration with Zed2 Camera

Tags: ros-humble, cameras, moveit2

Can anyone assist me in integrating the Zed2 Camera with my robot's URDF? Additionally, I aim to generate a Moveit2 configuration for my robot after integrating the camera. Could you please review the URDF code below? I am facing an error when trying to set up Moveit2 for my robot

````
<!-- Add one ZED Camera -->
<xacro:arg name="camera_name"   default="zed" />
<xacro:arg name="camera_model"  default="zed" />

<xacro:include filename="$(find zed_wrapper)/urdf/zed_macro.urdf.xacro" />
  <xacro:zed_camera name="$(arg camera_name)" model="$(arg camera_model)">
  </xacro:zed_camera>
    <joint name="$(arg camera_name)_joint" type="fixed">
   <origin xyz="0.12 0.0 0.25" rpy="0 0 0"/>
   <parent link="panda_link0"/>
   <child link="$(arg camera_name)_camera_link"/>
 </joint>

</robot>
```
````

Comment: I solved the Problem. I had forgotten to convert my Urdf to Xacro file. Now it works with Xacro file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Urdf file is a Xacro file and then add the Camera to the Robot Xacro file

Comment: Mark this as solved :)

Comment: i tried, it telling me i can do it only tomorrow

Comment: @Nikolai - Yes, you have to wait 48 hours, when you answer your own question. Please see [self answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: have you integrated the Zed_2 Camera with Ros2 Humble  Move-it2  on a Robot?